# I'm getting a #hash variable from the URL, then I'm trying to use it to open an accordion. What seems to be wrong with my code?

Tags: jquery

*URL example:* [www.example.com/services/#service1](http://www.example.com/services/#service1)

My various category elements each have a certain ID, the one I'm locating is #service1. I want to make that category active by adding "active-category" class to it. This is my code.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(hash).addClass("active-category");
```

when I do:
`alert(hash);`
I can see #service1

When I input it into `$(hash).addClass('active-category');`

The class isn't added to the element when I check in the console.

Comment: If `hash` really contains `#service1`, that code **will** add a class to the first `id="service1"` element in the DOM. Perhaps you have more than one and you're looking at one of the later ones?

Comment: See also (probably a dupetarget, actually): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Note: Please use `example.com` for placeholder domains. That's what it's for. There actually is a `website.com` and so I thought at first you were pointing us at a page with the problem DOM and code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, i figured it out the other day. You were correct it should be working correctly, I just had my jquery code placed in the wrong area. Doh! Thanks for the tip on example.com, i'll use that next time.